# Can I add pdf tags to R markdown document?

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown

I am trying to make a "accessible" or 508 compliant PDF using R markdown. To do this I need to have pdf tags attached to figure that provide alternative text. I also need to be able to add tags to section headers etc.

The idea is if you open the pdf in a pdf viewer that then the tags are read in in the "table of context" and allow a user to move between sections.

If you use a markdown header like

```
# header
```

R markdown seems to add a label to this so it appear in the table of context. I would like to be able to add these kind of labels manually as well.

Does anyone have any ideas of how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this using pandoc formatting (see http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html), for example the alt text for an image can be specified as `![alt text or image title](path/to/image)`

Comment: That seems like a really good idea- but I'm not quite sure how you would use pandoc  to format the body of a rmarkdown document? I understand how to use pandoc arguments in the yaml header but not in the body?

Comment: If you just add the relevant arguments (e.g. the alt text tag I provided) in your rmarkdown document they should behave as expected when knitted. You might want to look at the bookdown documentation for some extended examples.